# Prevent back-button cache on localhost

Tags: php, apache, security, browser-cache

I have Apache running PHP on a windows machine.

On my local website, if I log out as user the cookie is being emptied and after header redirect I'm no longer logged in on the site. On paper.

**But I can still use the browser back button and see the content that is meant for logged-in users only.**

But refreshing the page indeed shows that I am logged out and the content is not shown. But the back-cache disagrees.

On my live website that uses https there is no problem with back-cache like that.
But on local server, it happens.

How can I fix this?

This is what I use when a user logs out:

```
<?php
// LOG OUT
setcookie('cookie', '', time()+31449600, '/', NULL, FALSE, TRUE);
exit(header('Location: http://localhost/'));
?>
```

I use these headers in my php config file included on all php pages on the site:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y 00:01:00', strtotime('first day of this month')) . ' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()-1) . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

EDIT: I see now that the issue is related to "bfcache" (back-forward cache in browser). Still investigating..

*Google is not what it used to be when searching for issues like this..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having https (ssl) enabled solved the problem with cached pages and back button